# Insert new element in nested json object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have nested JSON like this with some nested levels:

```
{
  "Main": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "Sub1": [
        {
          "id": 2345,
          "description": "...",
          "Sub11": [
            {
              "subid": 6633,
              "xid": 5555
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 332,
      "Sub1": [
        {
          "xid": 5555,
          "description": "...",
          "Sub11": [
            {
              "subid": 6794
            },
            {
              "subid": 4444
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is just a example. I need to traverse through whole JSON and insert some json object (`NewNode`) for the element with property `xid: 5555`

Ex.
Before-

```
"Sub11": [
        {
          "subid": 6633,
          "xid": 5555
        }
      ]
```

After-

```
"Sub11": [
        {
          "subid": 6633,
          "xid": 5555,
          "NewNode":{
             "SomeProperty": "value"
          }
        }
      ]
```

I'm thinking to traverse through each node, check for the property name (`xid`). If it's value matches, then insert node (`NewNode`) there.

Is there easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show us what you have tried, and why it is not working?

Comment: > "...check for the property name (xid). If it's value matches, then insert node (NewNode) there."  Have you tried this? If you did, what was the result?

Comment: @Sabuncu trying to achieve this. Can get the desired behaviour for the fixed json. But since I have to traverse all the nodes, that is making the problem.

Comment: So you're looking for an optimized solution rather than traversing all nodes?  If so, please edit your question to reflect exactly what you are seeking in terms of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to do this pretty easily:

```
var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var matches = root.DescendantsAndSelf()
                  .OfType<JObject>()
                  .Where(x => x["xid"] != null && x["xid"].ToString() == "5555");

foreach (JObject jo in matches)
{
    jo.Add("NewNode", new JObject(new JProperty("SomeProperty", "value")));
}

Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DzJd3K